# objectWriter is not respecting JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY on ArrayList

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I'm trying to stop an empty list being present in JSON when using objectWritter.

Here is the object which contains a list of strings

```
public class Request {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    List<String> institutionIds;

    public Request(String institutionIds) {
        this.institutionIds = List.of(institutionIds);
    }

    public List<String> getInstitutionIds() {
        return institutionIds;
    }
}
```

and here is where I'm converting into json

```
public class ObjectWritterApplication {
    private static final ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var request = new Request("");

        var json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(request);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

My issue is the output contains an empty list which I don't want.

Output:

> {
> "institutionIds" : [ "" ]
> }

Answer (score 1):

The code line *new Request("")* creates a non-empty list with one element which is an empty string. Hence the output is correct.

If you want to exclude both *empty list* and a *list with only empty elements* - add the *content* attribute. Like this:

```
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY, content=Include.NON_EMPTY)
List<String> institutionIds;
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work for the above case